# PHP how to Compare Form inputs with database values | Laravel

Tags: php, database, forms, laravel

i need to compare Database Values with the inputs from Form this a a part of my code

```
 public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $website_info = WebsiteInfos::findOrFail($id);

        if ( $website_info->all() == $request->all()) {
            Session::flash('alert-info', 'No Change have been made');
            return redirect('admin/website_infos');

        } else {

           $website_info->update($requestData);

            Session::flash('alert-success', 'WebsiteInfos updated!');

            return redirect('admin/website_infos');

        }



}
```

i need to compare $request->all() with db value ! i try this ! the if is ignored and always Show me the Success alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to find the record in a query.

```
$website_info = WebsiteInfos::where([
    ['id', '=' ,$id],
    ['name', '=', $request->name],
    ['email', '=', $reqest->email]
])->first();

if ($website_info != null) {
    Session::flash('alert-info', 'No Change have been made');
    return redirect('admin/website_infos');
} else {
    $website_info->update($requestData);
    Session::flash('alert-info', 'No Change have been made');
    return redirect('admin/website_infos');
}
```

Comment: This look work for first condtion but whene i made change i receive this error `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function update() on null`

Comment: can you check function update and value of $requestData? I think you need to pass parameters according to query.

Comment: `$website_info = WebsiteInfos::findOrFail($id);` just adding this line to else condition

Answer (score 0):

I would do this. Database record can never be equal to the incoming request because of the presence of primary key, date or foreign keys. You should pluck  database values you want to compare with the request as follows

```
$db_records =$website_info->pluck(['name', 'url','any_other_field'])->toArray(); 
$incoming_request =$request->all(); //assumes this contains name, url, and any_other_field

if ( $db_records == $incoming_request) {
            Session::flash('alert-info', 'No Change have been made');
            return redirect('admin/website_infos');

        }
```

Comment: i try this and not work ,

i try `dd($db_records);` to verify waht i get , it show me `array:1 [▼
  55318152 => "Tunisia Rent a car"
]` 
Tunisia Rent a car (website_title)
55318152 is column (mobile 1)

`$db_records = $website_info->pluck('website_title', 'mobile1', 'mobile2', 'email', 'adresse')->toArray();`

Comment: I just made some changes` pluck(['name', 'url','any_other_field'])`

Comment: i had this error
`ErrorException (E_WARNING)
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: Where are you calling `strtolower` I think you should take  at laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) try or try and `dd($incoming_request)` and  `$db_records`. Let me know what you have there

Comment: thanks for helping i use the solution provided by parth in the answer bellow , that work nicly